# Ubuntu 20.04.2 bluetooth headphones stops playing/loses A2DP configuration

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm using Sony MDR-ZX770BN headphones. After I connect to headphones everything works, but only as long as I'm actually playing something. I can listen Spotify or youtube hours without problem, but if I pause songs/content it takes about ~2-10minutes till it stops working. Headphones does not lose bluetooth connection, but in sound settings I see that "configuration" slot disappears with selected option A2DP Sink:

[image: Sound settings while everything works]

[image: Sound settings after it stops working]

**`/var/log/syslog`** :

```
Mar 26 11:54:54  bluetoothd[876]: Start: Connection timed out (110)
Mar 26 11:54:54  pulseaudio[1889]: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_9B_0A_B5_3D_E5/sep1/fd1 (Input/output error)
Mar 26 11:54:54  bluetoothd[876]: avdtp_start failed
Mar 26 11:54:54  pulseaudio[1889]: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_9B_0A_B5_3D_E5/sep1/fd1 (Operation Not Authorized)
Mar 26 11:54:56  bluetoothd[876]: Abort: Connection timed out (110)
Mar 26 11:54:56  gsd-media-keys[2242]: Unable to get default sink
Mar 26 11:54:56  acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
Mar 26 11:54:56  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1980]: (II) config/udev: removing device MDR-ZX770BN (AVRCP)
Mar 26 11:54:56  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1980]: (**) Option "fd" "85"
Mar 26 11:54:56  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1980]: (II) event16 - MDR-ZX770BN (AVRCP): device removed
Mar 26 11:54:56  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1980]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 26 11:54:56  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1980]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed the problem. Not sure which one helped:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

changed `wifi.powersave` to `2`

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/input.conf
```

set `IdleTimeout=0`

Answer (score 0):

From time to time A2DP sink has disappeared, with only HFP remaining.
Removing /var/lib/bluetooth did not help.
Purging blueman, reinstalling it and rebooting has brought A2DP back
each time.
Not sure why this works for me.